# Problems clipping netCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf

I am trying to get a proof of concept going whereas I am taking a netCDF file from NOAA that has worldwide precip data for a particular year and "repartition" the data down to US state level.  I keep running into a situation where there's no data after performing the clip.

Using a shape file from https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip which has all states in a single file.

Using the netCDF file from ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/cpc_global_precip/precip.1988.nc.

Here's my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xarray
import geopandas
import glob
import os, sys, getopt
from shapely.geometry import mapping

def partition(shapeFile, ncDirectory, outDirectory, stateName):
    # Load the shape file that either has all the states or just one named state
    sf_all = geopandas.read_file(shapeFile)

    # Filter to our state
    sf = sf_all.loc[sf_all['NAME'] == stateName]

    # Get all the nc files in the ncDirectory so we can repartition all the models
    file_list = sorted(glob.glob(f'{ncDirectory}/*.nc'))

    for file in file_list:
        print(f'Working on: {outDirectory}/{stateName}/{os.path.basename(file)}')

        # Open the file and do some basics
        nc_file = xarray.open_dataset(file)
        nc_file.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
        nc_file.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)

        # Convert lon from 0,360 to -180,180 if needed
        if any(nc_file.coords['lon'] > 180 ):
            nc_file.coords['lon'] = (nc_file.coords['lon'] + 180) % 360 - 180
        
        # Convert lat from 0,360 to -180,180 if needed
        if any(nc_file.coords['lat'] > 180 ):
            nc_file.coords['lat'] = (nc_file.coords['lat'] + 180) % 360 - 180

        # Perform the actual clipping here based on the geometry of the {sf} variable which should just be our state
        clipped_nc = nc_file.rio.clip(sf.geometry.apply(mapping), crs="epsg:4326", drop=True)

        if os.path.exists(f'{outDirectory}/{stateName}/{os.path.basename(file)}'):
            os.removedirs(f'{outDirectory}/{stateName}/{os.path.basename(file)}')
        
        # Save the file to a new netCDF representing the state/model combination
        clipped_nc.to_netcdf(f'{outDirectory}/{stateName}/{os.path.basename(file)}')

def main(argv):
    shapeFile = ''
    stateName = ''
    ncDirectory = ''
    outDirectory = ''

    opt, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hf:n:o:s:",["shapedir=","ncdirectory=","outputdir=", "statename="])
    for opt, arg in opt:
        if opt =='-h':
            print('repartition.py -f <shapefile> -n <ncfiledirectory> -o <outputdir> -s <statename>')
            quit(0)
        elif opt in ("-f", "--shapefile"):
            shapeFile = arg.rstrip("/")
        elif opt in ("-n", "--ncdirectory"):
            ncDirectory = arg.rstrip("/")
        elif opt in ("-o", "--outputdir"):
            outDirectory = arg.rstrip("/")
        elif opt in ("-s","--statenames"):
            stateName = arg
        
    isExists = os.path.exists(f'{outDirectory}/{stateName}')
    if not isExists:
        os.makedirs(f'{outDirectory}/{stateName}')
    
    partition(shapeFile,ncDirectory,outDirectory, stateName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I am not normally a python user, I am actually more on the lines of C/C++/C#, but python is the requirement so running with it.
Other requirement, is this is a Windows environment (not my choice).  Maybe someday I will convince the powers to be that running Linux containers is not a bad thing and can be done in Azure so we can stay a "Microsoft Shop", but for now, Windows is it.

Comment: There is far too much going on here. Can you possibly convert the code into a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Not sure exactly how to respond with more than 500 chars so I can paste in the probably most minimalist code I can without loosing what could possibly be an issue.
Really, just the partition function is required.  One could just set the variables then paste the code of the function that way.

```
shapefile = '/mnt/c/Temp/p/cb_2018_us_state_500k/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp'
file = '/mnt/c/Temp/nc/test/precip.1988.nc'
stateName = 'Iowa'
outputfolder = f'/mnt/c/Temp/p/repartitioned/{stateName}'
```

Comment: As I said, there is too much redundancy in the code, and it's tough for anyone to make sense of it. For example, you have code for removing directories and writing output. You also haven't told us what line of code is causing the problem. Given it's not possible for someone to run the code, it's a big ask right now. Just strip it down to a few lines that will reproduce the issue with the 2 data files listed

Comment: I can't tell you which line of code is problematic, which is why I made this statement:
" I keep running into a situation where there's no data after performing the clip."

Also, I provided the link to the data files, and the code is the complete script, so it could be run by anyone, and by giving the links to the exact data files so it's very easy to copy the code into a .py file and run it with the exact data.

I am not a savvy python programmer so I don't know how to make the xarray perform a overwrite if the file exists, so I am checking if the file exists and if it does, delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the conversion of the longitude from the range [0, 360] to [–180, 180].
The longitudes must be sorted in increasing order, but by converting those above 180° to negative values, they are not sorted anymore.
Instead, after the conversion, the longitudes go from 0 to 180 and then from –180 to –0.
It seems as if clipping does not work in this case.

Since the US mainland is in negative longitudes, a simple workaround would be to remove everything between longitudes 0 and +180.
Then you're left with only negative longitudes, increasing from –180 to 0.
This can be done by adding the following line after opening the dataset with `xarray`:

```
nc_file = nc_file.where(nc_file.lon > 180, drop=True)
```

In this case, instead of the calculation with the modulo operator `%`, you can simply convert to longitudes in the desired range by:

```
nc_file["lon"] = nc_file.lon - 360
```

And I would suggest removing the conversion for latitudes, because they are always given with values between –90° and +90°.

So, a minimal working example (MWE) could be:

```
import xarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping

stateName = "Alaska"

sf_all = geopandas.read_file("cb_2018_us_state_500k/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp")
sf = sf_all.loc[sf_all["NAME"] == stateName]

nc_file = xarray.open_dataset("precip.1988.nc")

# Keep only longitudes between 180° and 360°
nc_file = nc_file.where(nc_file.lon > 180, drop=True)
# Convert longitudes from 180,360 to -180,0
nc_file["lon"] = nc_file.lon - 360

nc_file.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
nc_file.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)
clipped_nc = nc_file.rio.clip(sf.geometry.apply(mapping), crs="epsg:4326", drop=True)

# Show the result
clipped_nc.precip.mean("time").plot()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.show()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, the only issue would be expanding to using shapes in other countries, but the code as is does produce a file that is much smaller than I thought it would be.
When I open the new file up next to the old one, the data plots don't line up, i.e. I am seeing different data.

Comment: If I omit

`nc_file = nc_file.where(nc_file.lon > 180, drop=True)`

I get a "No data found in bounds" error

Comment: Going back to the original code and adding in a sortby() works great, until I hit a state that is Multipolygon.

Comment: Yes, `sortby` seems to be a good solution. My ideas would have been (i) to cut the array at 180° and concatenate the two parts again, with negative longitudes first. Or (ii) to choose only positive or only negative longitudes depending on the area of interest – but of course, this would not work for every area.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what appears to be the final version.  The resorting I think was the key to it all.
One of the things I may look at is regridding the data before going into the loop into a finer resolution, from .25 to 1/16th so that I can keep more information in the output based on the polygons.  Right now, .25 is quite a bit that get's lost in the output, unless someone knows how to include a grid point that's only partially contained in the shape instead of the current fully contained method.
This is all actually proof-of-concept code anyway, so maybe won't go much further myself with it, but it's nice to see doing things this way instead of using cube's and manually brute-forcing the data into the final result.
The only thing I will add, now that I'm thinking of it, is to remove all the leap-days from the file, because that's a requirement.
Anyway, enough babling, I want to thank everyone for their assistance in this.  Not only did I have to learn some new python, but had to really learn about netCDF, CRS, and all that jazz, so at the minimum, I learned a lot of new things in a short time.

```
import xarray as xr
import dask
import time
import geopandas as gpd
import sys, getopt
from shapely.geometry import mapping
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argv = sys.argv[1:]

    shapeFile = ''
    stateName = ''
    ncFileglob = ''
    ncFileDir = ''
    outDirectory = ''
    ncFileOutPartName = ''

    opt, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hf:g:n:o:s:",["shapedir=","ncFileDir=", "ncFileglob=","outputdir=", "statename="])
    for opt, arg in opt:
        if opt =='-h':
            print('repartition.py -f <shapefile> -n <ncFileDir> -g <ncFileglob> -o <outputdir> -s <statename>')
            quit(0)
        elif opt in ("-f", "--shapefile"):
            shapeFile = arg.rstrip("/")
        elif opt in ("-g", "--ncfileglob"):
            ncFileglob = arg.rstrip("/")
        elif opt in ("-o", "--outputdir"):
            outDirectory = arg.rstrip("/")
        elif opt in ("-s","--statename"):
            stateName = arg
        elif opt in ("-n","--ncFileDir"):
            ncFileDir = arg.rstrip("/")
    
    # Open the files and do some basics
    nc_file = xr.open_mfdataset(f'{ncFileDir}/{ncFileglob}', chunks={'time':365,'lat':100,'lon':100},parallel=True,use_cftime=False,decode_times=False)

    # Load the shape file that either has all the states or just one named state
    sf_all = gpd.read_file(shapeFile)

    # Convert lon from 0,360 to -180,180 if needed
    if any(nc_file.coords['lon'] > 180 ):
        nc_file.coords['lon'] = (nc_file.coords['lon'] + 180) % 360 - 180

    # Resort the lon dimension so that it starts at -180 and increases
    nc_file = nc_file.sortby(nc_file.lon)

    # Set the dataset CRS and signify the x,y dimension labels
    nc_file.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
    nc_file.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)

    # Get the first and last years for part of the filename
    # Extract the time dimension
    time_data = nc_file['time']

    # Find the first and last time values
    first_time = time_data.min().values
    last_time = time_data.max().values

    # And finally Convert time values to string representations of years
    first_year = first_time.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(str)
    last_year = last_time.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(str)

    # Start building the later part of the filename
    ncFileOutPartName = f"{nc_file.attrs['cmip6_source_id']}_{nc_file.attrs['scenerio']}_{nc_file.attrs['variant_label']}_{first_year}-{last_year}"

    # Record the start of processing all the polygons
    overall_start_time = time.time()

    # Loop through all the shapes in the shapefile
    for index, row in sf_all.iterrows():
        polygon_name = row['NAME']
        print(f'Working on {polygon_name}', end='')
        
        sf = sf_all.loc[sf_all["NAME"] == polygon_name]
        try:   
            # Record the start time of the code run for this polygon
            start_time = time.time()             
            # Perform the actual clipping here based on the geometry of the {sf} variable which should just be our state
            clipped_nc = nc_file.rio.clip(sf.geometry.apply(mapping), crs="epsg:4326", drop=True)

            # Build the final filename
            nc_repartitioned_file = f'{outDirectory}/{polygon_name}_{ncFileOutPartName}.nc'

            # Write the file out for the polygon
            clipped_nc.to_netcdf(nc_repartitioned_file)

            # Record the start time of the code run for this polygon
            end_time = time.time()

            # Calculate the elapsed time
            elapsed_time = round((end_time - start_time) / 60,2)

            print(f' : Completed in {elapsed_time} minutes')

        except Exception as error:
            print(f'  there was a problem')
            print("The error was:", error)

    # Record the start of processing all the polygons
    overall_end_time = time.time()

    # Calculate the elapsed time of processing all the polygons
    overall_elapsed_time = round((overall_end_time - overall_start_time) / 60,2)

    # Get the total number of polygons we had to deal with
    total_polygons = sf_all['NAME'].count()

    # now report everything
    print(f'The run for {total_polygons} polygons took {overall_elapsed_time} minutes to complete')

    # Close the dataset and cleanup
    nc_file.close()
```